# Acr.UserDialogs problems in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have just added `UWP` to my `Xamarin`-project, but I get some wierd behavior from `Acr.UserDialogs`.

When using `PromptAsync` and `Confirm` I get some `ArgumentNullException`.
How can I fix these?

The other problem is, that `SuccessToast` never disappears like they do on `iOS` and `Android`, and they did on `Silverlight`. 
Is there a workaround for this?

I am using these NuGet packages (in UWP project)

```
Acr.UserDialogs                              v5.2.2
Acr.XamForms.UserDialogs                     v5.0.0
Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform   v5.1.0
MR.Gestures                                  v1.3.4
SQLite.Net-PCL                               v3.1.1
Xam.Plugins.Settings                         v2.1.0
Xamarin.Forms                                v2.2.0.45
Xamarin.Insights                             v1.12.3
XLabs.Forms                                  v2.2.0-pre02
```

I hope for your help.

**UPDATE**
From the `StackTrace` I figured out, you have to set the `PlaceHolder` to `string.Empty`, as it per default is set to `null`, which `UWP` does not support.

Comment: what version of Xamarin Forms and Acr.UserDialogs you are using?

Comment: I have added NuGet references now

Comment: Isn't Xamarin.Forms 2.2.0.45 stable?

Comment: This could be a bug in Acr.UserDialogs. I guess it would good to open a issue here: https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/issues

Comment: I did that, and from the StackTrace I figured out, you have to set the PlaceHolder, as it is not supported to be set to null